# Insert new ChatterMessage message object

Tags: chatter, connect-api

I'm trying to create a Chatting app within one of my pages, I'm able to query for the ChatterMessage messages and such but I am unable to insert a new message. I realize there is the ConnectApi for this purpose however the 60 messages per hour limit could be an issue. Has anyone figured out how to insert new ChatterMessage messages. I've tied creating a new ChatterMessage object and inserting it however doing so throws a strange error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insertion of the `ChatterMessage` sObject isn't allowed. As you mentioned, you'll need to use either the `ConnectApi.ChatterMessages` [class in Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterMessages_static_methods.htm%23apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterMessages_sendMessage), or the [Chatter REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_users_messages_general.htm).

Note that the [60 requests per hour guideline](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Chatter_API:_Examples,_Best_Practices,_and_Tips) applies to checking for new messages, not inserting them. There is a much higher limit for the number of messages you can insert. Specifying the exact number isn't possible because it depends on how often you call other `ConnectApi` methods, but it's much higher than a typical client would need.